# Are HTML data attributes and jQuery's .data() same thing?

Tags: html, jquery, custom-data-attribute, jquery-data

In HTML it's possible to set custom 'data-' attributes to elements like

```
<div data-blah="blah">
```

The jQuery framework has methods to do similar things (`.data()` etc). My question is do the jQuery methods just manipulate and read these html5 data attributes, or they are referring to different jQuery-type data-attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, totally different things. jQuery's .data() existed even before W3C added these to HTML version 5.

See https://api.jquery.com/data/ for details.

To get an HTML data- attribute value from an HTML tag, try:

```
jQuery('selector here').attr('data-blah');
```