# html "data-" attribute as javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

Is it possible to register a html data-attribute as the name of a javascript variable?

What I am talking about is something like this:

```
<form>
  <input data-varName="test1" />
  <input data-varName="test2" />
</form>

$('form').find('input').each(function() {
  var $(this).attr('data-varName') = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Rel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to store your variables in an object, and then use object-notation to assign values to variables:

```
<form>
  <input data-varName="test1" />
  <input data-varName="test2" />
</form>

var allVariables = {};

$('form input').each(function(){
  allVariables[ $(this).data('varName') ] = $(this).val();
});
```

Or, in plain JavaScript:

```
Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('form input') ).forEach(function(el) {
    allVariables[ el.dataset.varName ] = el.value;
});
```

Which, given the above HTML, would result in an `allVariables` object like:

```
{
  'test1' : test1Value,
  'test2' : test2Value
}
```

Obviously, you could also use the `window` global object, and register variables to that instead but that carries the concern that variables of the `window` object are global and can be over-written by plugins elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Actually this would work for what I need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax to target `data` attributes is:

`var myVar = $(this).data("varName");`

See here for more info:

https://api.jquery.com/data/

EDIT --

This doesn't address the issue of how to set the variable name, but it is the correct method for targeting data attributes.

Comment: I'm not using the jQuery data attribute, I am using HTML data-*.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Another reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113046/are-html-5-data-and-jquery-data-same-thing

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, jQuery now uses `.data` to target HTML5 data attributes - see this more detailed link: https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5.

Comment: Also, see this SO post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11673313/4008056